# UAC error while installing Xampp 1.8.35 on windows 8

Tags: windows, xampp, localhost

I am trying to install xampp but before installation it gives me the following error:

[image: Error]

I have disabled UAC and it gives me this error.When I press ok and install the thing anyway it still won't let start apache and my sql up. Also installation was done in Program file instead of Program files (x86) as specified in the pciture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `xampp` installation directory. 
Right click on `"xampp-control"` then choose `"Run as administrator"`
If prompted, choose `Yes`

You do not have to disable UAC. 
You are simply getting this message because the application was started with *normal* user rights, while the application needs **administrator** rights to be able to activate *Apache* and *MySQL* services.